# Como puedo exportar un script de Python con los modulos que utiliza en forma de archivo?

Tags: python, packages, exe, module.exports

Estoy intentando exportar un script de python que usa unos modulos pesados a un ordenador sin internet.

De alguna manera puedo exportar de manera conjunta el script junto con los modulos en forma de archivo? De manera que si llamo a los modulos desde el script, estos sean importados directamente desde un archivo adjunto

También he leido que puedo convertir el py en un exe. Si lo hago, los modulos que utilizo en dicho script son incluidos en el exe?

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola @Carlos Santamaría. Bienvenido a la comunidad en español de StackOverflow. Creo que te has equivocado de idioma al plantear tu pregunta ;)

Comment: Perdona, no me habia dado cuenta!

Comment: Puedes crear un ejecutable con todas sus dependencias incluidas utilizando [PyInstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/)